# Range Partitioning in Pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, partitioning

Say I have a dataset with 1,000,000 ids. How would I go about partitioning by range for 100 partitions. I have seen the RangePartitioner class within Scala, but it does not seem to be available in PySpark API.

I have a very large dataset and am currently partitioning by the unique id, but this is creating too many partitions. I want to know best practice on range partitioning in PySpark

```
df.write.partitionBy('unique_id').mode('overwrite').csv(file://test/)
```

This puts every id in its own partition.

I cannot seem to find any documentation on range partitioning in PySpark.

Comment: Are you looking for `df.repartition(100, 'unique_id').write.mode('overwrite').csv('file:://test/')`? [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.repartition)

Comment: @pault I will test this, but what I am looking for is say the id's are in sequential order from id 0 to id 1000000. I want the DF to be partitioned where 0-10000 are in a partition 10000-etc in the next and so on.

Comment: Thank you for the docs I was looking for repartitionByRange!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For pyspark version 2.4 and above, you can use [`pyspark.sql.DataFrame.repartitionByRange`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.repartitionByRange):

```
df.repartitionByRange(100, 'unique_id').write.mode('overwrite').csv('file:://test/')
```

Comment: How to do rangepartition at pyspark rdd level?

Comment: is there any difference between saying 'repartitionByRange' before .write() ?  i.e., df.repartitionByRange(n, col).write() vs df.write().repartitionByRange(n, col)